# How i can call function inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I would like to call a function that is inside another function, that function will clear the timeout.

I have tried the following code, but without success:

```js
async function Blast2() {
  const delayTime = 1000;
  const timer = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

  function ClearDelayTime() {
    return clearTimeout(blast);
  }

  const blast = setTimeout(function () {
    let blast =
      "SELECT * FROM admin_contacts,temporary WHERE blast_status = 'sended'";
    db.query(blast, async function (err, result, field) {
      if (err) throw err;

      loop: {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          console.log(result[i].telefone);
          await timer(delayTime); // then the created Promise can be awaited
        }
      }
    });
  }, delayTime);
}

// I Want Call the function ClearDelayTime() inside Blast2()
Blast2().ClearDelayTime();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do more broadly? There is probably a simpler way of writing this code

Comment: When executing Blast(), it takes a list of numbers in mysql and in a specific timeout it displays number one by one until the end of the list. By clicking on ClearDelayTime() it would stop the execution of this loop.

Comment: I hate to see duplicate variable names, even if they don't have the same scope, and I don't think I'm the only one...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Based on how JS works, and the conventions used when writing JS, by calling it `Blast2` you are implying that this is supposed to be a constructor function, to be called as `const b = new Blast2()`, with a prototype that you can call functions on (e.g. `b.clearDelayTime()`. If that's your intention, rewrite `Blast2` as a class. If it's not, and it's a true function (i.e. "it does a thing and exits once it's done that thing") then you can return that function, but then don't make `Blast2` an `async` function, because _it_ isn't doing anything that needs awaiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code. It now immediately returns a function that can be used to abort.

```js
const db = {
  query: (sql, callback) => callback(undefined,
    [{telefone:1},{telefone:2},{telefone:3},{telefone:4},{telefone:5}])
}

function blast2() {

  const delayTime = 1000
  const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

  let sql = "SELECT * FROM admin_contacts,temporary WHERE blast_status = 'sended'";

  let abort = false;

  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      (async () => {
        for(let i=0; i<result.length && !abort; i++) {
          console.log(result[i].telefone);
          await timer(delayTime);
        }
      })();
    }
  })

  return () => abort = true;

}
let abortFunc = blast2();
setTimeout(abortFunc, 2500);
```

Comment: ReferenceError:  Cannot access 'db' before initialization

Comment: @Cole you can see that my code runs perfectly in the sandbox. The problem must be in your own dev environment, which I have no visibility over. You know you need to remove the part where I did `const db=...`, because that's just for testing purposes?

Comment: I already found the problem haha, your code is right, it worked like a glove.
Bless!

Comment: `let abortFunc = blast2();` execute the function. How i can call the abortFunc like a "button".

Comment: @Cole just make the onclick of the button call abortFunc(), which will be in global scope

Comment: I have tried this, but when i call  `abortFunc()` then execute the blast2() again.

Comment: @Cole I can't see your entire code, so it's very hard for me to guess what might be going wrong

Comment: How i can add a terminator, example function `blast2(abort), blast2(start)`

Comment: I don't understand your question. abortFunc() already is a terminator... maybe you mean something else by the word

Answer (score 1):

Your function `Blast2` doesn't return anything. If you want to call a function inside it, you could return and store it using a variable, then call it.

Something like this:

```js
const f1 = () => {
  console.log('f1 called')
  const f2 = () => {
    console.log('f2 called')
  }
  
  return f2
}

const returnedFunction = f1()

console.log(returnedFunction())
```

Comment: I edited, i need do this: ?

`function ClearDelayTime(){
            return clearTimeout(blast)
        }`

Comment: added a snippet, hope it helps